# selected item from combobox used with another get- process

Tags: powershell, powercli, vsphere

Below code grabs the available datacenter names and adds them to a combobox ok.

```
function fill_dclist 
{
$comboBox1.Items.Clear()
$dclist = Get-Datacenter
foreach ($dc in $dclist)
{
$comboBox1.Items.add($dc.name.toString())
}
```

the below code should read the selected item in the above combobox and use this to search against that datacenter name and display all VMs from that datacenter.

```
function fill_updatevmlist 
{
$selecteddc = ($comboBox1.SelectedItem)
$dcvms = Get-datacenter -Name $selecteddc | get-VM 
foreach ($dcvm in $dcvms)
{
[void]$listBox1.Items.Add($vm.name)
}
}
```

Combobox code:

```
###DROPDOWN DC SELECT LIST###
$comboBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = $True
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 7
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 7
$comboBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 21
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 121
$comboBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$comboBox1.TabIndex = 0
$comboBox1.add_Click({

fill_dclist
fill_updatevmlist

})
```

Currently getting the following errors

```
Get-Datacenter : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument th
at is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\Olly\Documents\Dropbox\_PROJECT\First Stage\Code\draft.ps1:251 char:30
+ $dcvms = Get-datacenter -Name <<<<  $selecteddc | get-VM 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Datacenter], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetDat 
   acenter

Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item"
At C:\Users\Olly\Documents\Dropbox\_PROJECT\First Stage\Code\draft.ps1:254 char:26
+ [void]$listBox1.Items.Add <<<< ($vm.name)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any gurus out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As last time, your my testsubject here since I don't have vspehere. :) Try:

```
function fill_updatevmlist 
{
    $selecteddc = ($comboBox1.SelectedItem.toString())
    $dcvms = Get-datacenter -Name $selecteddc | get-VM 
    foreach ($dcvm in $dcvms)
    {
        [void]$listBox1.Items.Add($dcvm.name)
    }
}
```

You had typo in foreach loop. I'm unsure about the first error. It might be because you try to update the listbox before anything is selected in combobox. So if the above does not work, try to include this too:

```
function fill_dclist 
{
    $comboBox1.Items.Clear()
    $dclist = Get-Datacenter
    foreach ($dc in $dclist)
    {
        $comboBox1.Items.add($dc.name.toString())
    }
}
```

Remove that combobox add_click thing your doing. combobox is not a button. Make sure you call `fill_dclist` ONLY on form load(also if you have a refresh datacenter button). HOWEVER, don't call `fill_updatevmlist` on load. ONLY call `fill_updatevmlist` on combobox1's selectedIndexChanged event. You assign this using ex: `$comboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged({fill_updatevmlist})` . If you make sure updatevmlist is only called after the combobox has a NEW value, it should work.

Comment: Hi Graimer! The second code works however when you click on the drop down list it selects the bottomest item first and the  function fill_updatevmlist displays this selection straight away. is there a way to only call fill_updatevmlist once the click on an drop down list item is done?

Comment: sorry yes they both work together - how do I stop it automatically taken bottom item on opening the list?

Comment: I've edited my post now where I removed it, and tell you what you should fix. What I get from this though, is that you should read up on events, actions, and c#/powershell in general. Because you don't understand the code your using, and that will make you bump into problem after problem. take some time, read some c# to understand how these forms work.